# Dynamic number of buttons calling a javascript function, function not getting called

Tags: javascript, html, django

I developed a web app on the django framework that calls on instagram to get photos from a nearby area on google maps.

So, I'm trying to add favorites functionality and I am able to save the favorites to the database and retrieve them, however, when I am constructing the google map markers corresponding to the favorited places, a button that calls a function isn't working. 
It is giving me **unexpected identifier {  -- line 2** error, and it's always this error.

Here's the code that attempts to do that:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
   var favorite_markers = [
       {% for favorite in user.favorite_set.all %}
           // The line below is the one that doesn't work and gives off the
           // strange error. The button shows up, but when I click it nothing 
           // happens and I get that error on the javascript console.
           [ "<button onclick='InstagramInit('{{ favorite.lat }}', '{{ favorite.lng }}', '{{ favorite.place_name }}')'> lol </button>",
            "{{ favorite.lat }}",
            "{{ favorite.lng }}"],
       {% endfor %}
   ];


    var favorite_infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), favorite_marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < favorite_markers.length; i++) {  
        favorite_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(favorite_markers[i][1], favorite_markers[i][2]),
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(favorite_marker, 'click', (function(favorite_marker, i) {
            return function() {
                favorite_infowindow.setContent(favorite_markers[i][0]);
                favorite_infowindow.open(map, favorite_marker);
            }
        })(favorite_marker, i));
    }        
{% endif %}
```

Also I know the function works, because elsewhere I call it with searched places, but it doesn't seem to work when I do it here...

Any ideas where I'm screwing up?

Comment: You have an unmatched `}` on the line before `{% endif %}`

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad indentation, the last '}' belongs to the for loop.

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: That's the strange thing, the error shows up on line 2, which is where the <html> tag is located at.
I read about it and it may be due to how searching for a function is done in javascript. But I'm not sure, it was unclear.